# How to convert a char to the associated escape sequence?

Tags: c++, text-processing

I need to transform escape sequences contained in non-literal strings (so that they are split in more characters, the first one being `\` and the others being just `n`, `r` or even octal codes etc.) to the actual character represented by that escape sequence.

My first thought was it could be possible using a macro (like `#define to_escape(x) '\(x)'` which doesn't work), but I wonder if there actually is a way like that and if there are better ways.

Of course I could use a simple switch statement for escapes like `\a`, `\f` and similars, but then how would I handle all the octal and hexadecimal escapes?

Comment: What is the "actual character" represented by `'\n'`? Or, to put it more generally, what, specifically, do you want the result of this transformation to be? Keeping in mind that `'\n`' **is** a character.

Comment: I want it to be the same character you get when manually typing that sequence as a string or character literal, i.e. a newline for '\n', a tab for '\t' and so on.

Comment: Again: what do you want to get when you see `'\n'`? Calling it "newline" doesn't answer that; it just replaces a portable character with a non-portable name.

Comment: This is getting embarassing. I meant the character with code 10 (decimal base) on the Ascii table.

Comment: Okay: `'\n'` becomes 10. The point is that being clear on what you're trying to do is the most important step in figuring out how to do it.

Comment: "I have these requirements; how do I program them?" Poor question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

you can go for this byte allocation

```
\'  single quote            byte 0x27 in ASCII encoding
\"  double quote            byte 0x22 in ASCII encoding
\?  question mark           byte 0x3f in ASCII encoding
\\  backslash               byte 0x5c in ASCII encoding
\a  audible bell            byte 0x07 in ASCII encoding
\b  backspace               byte 0x08 in ASCII encoding
\f  form feed - new page    byte 0x0c in ASCII encoding
\n  line feed - new line    byte 0x0a in ASCII encoding
\r  carriage return         byte 0x0d in ASCII encoding
\t  horizontal tab          byte 0x09 in ASCII encoding
\v  vertical tab            byte 0x0b in ASCII encoding
```

check if their addresses match their hexa-addresses and you can retrieve the following character.

Comment: This is basically the switch statement I described for single character escapes. But how do I handle numerical escapes, like `\077`?

Comment: You can't iterate over a character, the only way it to use manipulate bits of that character to generate what you are looking for. These are some of the escape character listing. Google and look up for their complete list. @user6245072